# I can't set the uipickerview datasource and delegate from an outside file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipickerview

I can't seem to set my outside pickerview datasource and delegate to my main view. Is there away I can set it? I want to keep my pickerview in a separate file due to other future views that might use it

This is my custom picker view

```
final class LenghtPickerView: UIPickerView, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    let feet = Array(4...7)
    let inches = Array(1...11)

    private var textFieldBeginEdited: UITextField?

    var selectedValue: String {
        get {
            return "\(feet[selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]) ft \(inches[selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]) in"
        }
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if component == 0 {
            return feet.count
        } else {
            return inches.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if component == 0 {
            return String(feet[row])
        } else {
            return String(inches[row])
        }
    }
}
```

and in my main view declaring it 
`private let lenghtPickerView = LenghtPickerView()`
also tried
`private let lenghtPickerView: LenghtPickerView = LenghtPickerView()`

cant set the datasource and delegate in order for the data to be render

```
lenghtPickerView.delegate = self
lenghtPickerView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: What is the use case for this LenghtPickerView?  Are you just trying to return a value from the selected pickerView?

Comment: my data is not rendering at the pickerview thats all @valosip

Comment: added a new answer, it should populate your pickerview with the data

Answer (score 0):

If you set

`lenghtPickerView.delegate = self`

`lenghtPickerView.dataSource = self`

from your Main View.

That means delegate & datasource of your picker should be adopted in your Main View

Comment: it giving me this error.."Cannot assign value of type 'mainViewController' to type 'UIPickerViewDelegate?' "

Comment: Please update your topic and show me the code in your Main View @Jhn

Comment: For this to work, you will need to implement UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate methods in your mainViewController, thats why you're getting that error, because your viewcontroller does not conform to the pickerviewdelegates.

Comment: is it i already done that in the separately? in my LenghtPickerView @valosip

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get your data to show up, you can simply set the dataSource and delegate like so:

```
lenghtPickerView.delegate = lenghtPickerView
lenghtPickerView.dataSource = lenghtPickerView
```

https://ibb.co/2gRVTxJ

But if I understand your question correctly, and you're trying to get a value from a pickerview and set the textfield value from it and make it reusable, you might want to do a little differently.
Here is one option:
the LengthPickerViewDelegate are optional, if you don't need done besides setting the textfield.text value

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white

    let pickerViewTextField = LengthPickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))
    pickerViewTextField.placeholder = "Select Length"
    pickerViewTextField.center = self.view.center
    pickerViewTextField.pickerDelegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(pickerViewTextField)
}
}

extension MainViewController: LengthPickerViewDelegate {
func doSomething() {
    //
    print("Picker view value changed")
}
}

protocol LengthPickerViewDelegate: class {
    // do something, pass values to mainVC if needed
    func doSomething()
}

class LengthPickerView: UITextField {
let feet = Array(4...7)
let inches = Array(1...11)

lazy var pickerView: UIPickerView = {
    let pickerView = UIPickerView()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self
    return pickerView
}()

weak var pickerDelegate: LengthPickerViewDelegate?

var selectedValue: String {
    get {
        return "\(feet[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]) ft \(inches[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]) in"
    }
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.inputView = pickerView
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}

extension LengthPickerView: UIPickerViewDataSource {
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if component == 0 {
        return feet.count
    } else {
        return inches.count
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if component == 0 {
        return String(feet[row])
    } else {
        return String(inches[row])
    }
}
}

extension LengthPickerView: UIPickerViewDelegate {
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    // do something with selected values, if you need a calculation done
    self.pickerDelegate?.doSomething()

    // or if you only want to set the textfield value
    self.text = selectedValue
}
}
```

Comment: still my pickerView doesnt render my data.

Comment: @Jhn what triggers the pickerview, a textfield?

Comment: @Jhn Updated answer with a quick fix and a longer approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to do delegate pickerView in UIView class, try this.

check  `awakeFromNib()` function.

Because mine was looks like this

```
override class func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        pickerView.delegate = self //Cant delegate
        pickerView.dataSource = self 
}
```

After a couple minutes I figured out something different here and I delete the "class" from "override class func awakeFromNib(){} "

Now its working I can delegate and my `awakeFromNib()` function look like this:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
}
```